# Как запустить программу, запретив ей любые интернет соединения?

Tags: python-3.6

Допустим мне нужно запустить хром, при этом, запретить ему любые подключения к сети, как будто я физически отключил соединение, но только для одного окна (хром здесь для примера, это должно работать с любой программой).

Желательно, чтобы можно было отслеживать какие сетевые подключения пытается сделать программа.

Можете рассказать как это сделать?

P.S. В командной строке windows, python, c++/c/c#  ... (любой язык яп)

Comment: Просто запустить в виртуальной машине или контейнере без сетевого соединения? :)

Comment: В файрволле запретить интернет активность.

Comment: Насчёт виртуальной машины. Идея, которая приходит в первую очередь, но в основном требует большой производительности. Можно использовать sandboxie, но в моём случае это не то, мне нужен полный api, чтобы я мог контролировать всё (говорю как диктатор какой-то ;)   )